# Fastest way to find 2s-complement of a number is to get the rightmost set bit and flip everything to the left of it

Tags: c

I need to implement this in C language using bit masking.  I am new to bit masking concept.

Can anyone please help me out to implement this using bit masking?

Code:

```
int a = 0b00001010;
int mask = 0b00000001; 
int i, cnt;
char a[8]; 

for(cnt=0; cnt<16; cnt++) { 
    i = a & mask; 
    mask = mask<<1; 
    if (i==0) { 
        a[cnt] = 0;
    } else { 
        a[cnt] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what has been tried? How is this not working as expected? *Surely* there is lots of documentation/examples that covers the use of bit-wise operators in C..

Comment: I tried to use bitwise AND and to left shift to find first set bit from right side and after I am still trying to figure it out. How to invert all bits

Comment: The main thing is I have to use integer number and store the result into char array.

Comment: Cool - might want to include the current code, input and output and in question. Anyway, to "invert all bits" use `~` (Bit-wise Complement) operator. Storing the result into a char (array) sounds like separate from bit fiddling .. unless the task to *first* covert it into char[32] or somenonsense/thing? Hopefully the assignment's wording is precise..

Comment: It may be the "fastest way" in some abstract algorithmic sense, but I'll be surprised if anything you can implement will come anywhere close to `~x+1`, or `-x`.

Comment: Code: Int a=0b00001010; int mask =0b00000001; int i, cnt; char a[8]; for(cnt=0; cnt<16;cnt++) { i=a&mask; mask=mask<<1; if(i==0) {a[cnt]=0;} else a[cnt]=1;}